# Автоматическое считывание информации с сайта

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток, второй раз за сегодня 8-)

Есть сайт [падающий фобос грунт](http://n2yo.com/?s=37872). У сайта с правого боку телеметрия, но данные в исходном коде страницы не отображаются. 2-3 темы назад я уже интересовался, как считывать данные со стороннего сайта, что хотел применить и к этому, но не могу.

Объясните, как считать телеметрию? Хочется что-то в роде раз в 10 секунд считывать значение другим сайтом, и записывать его в таблицу, или каждый раз при обновлении данных. Эта штука должна упасть через 2-3 недели, так, что хотелось бы считать телеметрию до этого срока.

P.S. Максимум, до которого докопался я, это классы, которые уходят в скрипт n2yo1000.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно, все дело в `/js/n2yo10.js`, там в начале файла идет:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
    // ...
    var r = Math.random() * Date.parse(new Date());
    // satlist на данный момент 37872
    var url = "http://"+window.location.hostname+"/sat/jtest.php?s="+satlist+"&r="+r;

    $.getJSON(url,
        function(data){
                sArray=data;
                // ...
                populateInstantTrk();
                durID = setInterval ("populateInstantTrk()", DURATION*1000);
        }
    );
    // ...
});
```

Дальше все дело происходит в `populateInstantTrk()`

```
function populateInstantTrk() {
        var r = Math.random() * Date.parse(new Date());
        var url =
            "http://"
            +window.location.hostname
            +"/sat/instant-tracking.php?s="+satlist
            +"&hlat="+homeLat+"&hlng="+homeLng+"&d="+DURATION
            +"&r="+r+"&tz=" + intTimezone_now_tzstring;
        // Тут в конце концов получается что-то типа:
        // http://n2yo.com/sat/instant-tracking.php?s=37872&hlat=55.755786&hlng=37.617633&d=300&r=1301027283608.8657&tz=GMT+04:00
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                //  тут мы все данные выводим
        });

}
```

Собственно ни каких чудес - обычные запросы, другое дело что из своего javascript-а может не пойти, так как это javascript cross site ajax, а там есть некоторые ограничения

Comment: а именно - нельзя делать ajax запросы на другой домен :D

Comment: Дык вопрос-то не про то что-бы использовать эти данные на сайте, а что нужно сделать что-бы получить эти данные в свое php-скрипте с последующей записью всех данных в БД.

У человека возник вопрос - как получить эти данные, собственно ответ - список URL-ей по которым можно взять данные

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_content(http://n2yo.com/?s=37872);
```

а оттуда выдергиваешь нужную тебе таблицу, она находится в

```
<div id="paneldata" style="visibility: hidden">
  <table>*****</table>
</div>
```

Comment: file_get_content это вроде пхп....
да и как веб-сервер на котором сайт отреагирует на частые обращения к нему если например не раз в 10 секунд брать , а раз в 1-2 секунды?

Comment: ну да PHP.

Как часто брать информацию это ты сам решай, хоть раз в час. Да там нормальный сервер на него ежесекундно по 1К заходят. просто если там что-то упадет то ты просто напросто не получишь информации через функцию, вот и все.